# How to access protected properties in gtmetrix API

Tags: php, api

I am using GTMATRIX api to fetch pagespeedscore and other data. and I am using this library https://github.com/entrecore/php-gtmetrix. so far I created index.php file and get the results as:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use Entrecore\GTMetrixClient\GTMetrixClient;
use Entrecore\GTMetrixClient\GTMetrixTest;

$client = new GTMetrixClient();
$client->setUsername('shahroze.nawaz@cloudways.com');
$client->setAPIKey('e16345e33e9d3371b2d64bb93dc56189');

$client->getLocations();
$client->getBrowsers();
$test = $client->startTest('https://www.cloudways.com/en/');

//Wait for result
while ($test->getState() != GTMetrixTest::STATE_COMPLETED &&
    $test->getState() != GTMetrixTest::STATE_ERROR) {
    $final = $client->getTestStatus($test);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($final);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will giving the following output:

[image]

The problem is I can't able to access the protected properties and the file URL's any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you got returned an object `GTMetrixTest`

if you will have a look at [source code of this class](https://github.com/entrecore/php-gtmetrix/blob/v1/src/GTMetrixTest.php) you will realize that all protected things have public getters.

So, reading the class, you will find this public function:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getResources() {
    return $this->resources;
}
```

So in your code, you will later on call

```
$resources = $final->getResources();
var_dump($resources); //should return accessible array
```